# Sessions: can't check if cookie is set

Tags: php, cookies

I've got a code which sets cookies when person logs in:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
setcookie("user", $db_username, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
```

then checking for them:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
    exit();
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't redirect me to google.By the way my login system works with ajax, so I'm just curious if it have something to do. I've checked in my browser for cookies and there is "user" cookie so why doesn't my code work...?

Comment: Do you have `session_start();`?

Comment: You are not checking for the cookie at all after setting it, so what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: Yes,I have session_start();. I'm checking if cookie is set

Comment: @Donny: You are not checking in the code we can see though. And I still don't understand what the cookie has to do with the question -- this cookie and your session are mostly independent.

Comment: Just to make sure, as you seem to be using the terms interchangeably in your questions. Cookies are not the same as Session?

Comment: I'm new into whole cookies and sessions things,guys, are you trying to help me or kill me?

Comment: Trying to understand the whole problem :P. The code you've posted would work, so there must be something else you haven't posted which is the reason why it's giving you your problem.

Comment: Hmmm I could show you the whole code wherever is needed,but not sure which part I should copy/paste.

Comment: By the way,the main thing I want to do is check if cookies are set, then do some stuff